# How do I copy data to another sheet over multiple columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a 2 sheet Excel book. The first sheet has a number of columns,filled with data including 2 columns with peoples names (surnames and Christian names).

The second sheet has 6 columns in which I have inserted formula to extract the names (from sheet 1) but spread the data over the 6 columns in order to print the names on a single sheet (landscape).

My problem is that in order to activate the formula in sheet 2 correctly, I need to highlight the top cells and drag them down.

How can I accomplish this in a fully automatic way?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Please [edit] your question to tell us what you've already tried to resolve this. Does it actually have to be copied or can it just be referencing of the cells (`=Sheet1!A1`) from the first sheet?

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the sheet2 data into a Table.  You can achieve this by selecting all the Rows and Columns, then going to the Insert ribbon and choosing Table.

Once you have a Table, then any formula you enter for a row is automatically copied to all the other rows for that column.  This also extends as you add new rows.